# Run cosmosdb commands from powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, powershell-cmdlet

I am trying to connect to azure cosmosdb from my local machine via powershell but every command I tried to run it returns the `"Argument passed in is not serializable."`
Here are a few of my commands,

```
Get-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName "cosmosbackup"

Invoke-AzCosmosDBSqlDatabaseThroughputMigration -ResourceGroupName "cosmosbackup" -AccountName "liabilitydata"  -Name liability

New-AzCosmosDBSqlContainer -AccountName "liabilitydata"-DatabaseName "dailyliability"-ResourceGroupName "cosmosbackup"-Name schemes -PartitionKeyPath /Id -PartitionKeyKind Hash

Get-AzCosmosDBSqlContainer `
    -ResourceGroupName "cosmosbackup" `
    -AccountName "liabilitydata" `
    -DatabaseName "dailyliability"
```

All of them fail for the same reason `Argument passed in is not serializable.`

Am I missing something? Please help

Comment: it works fine, where are you running it? in portal?

Comment: I am running it locally in a powershell window

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that you need to set the context for running the script,

**Step 1 :** Connect with your Azure account

```
Connect-AzAccount
```

**Step 2 :** Pass the resource group and the cosmosdb account name as follows,

```
Get-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName cosmosbackup
```